# Python statsmodels.glm - TypeError when family=Poisson()

Tags: python, typeerror, statsmodels, glm

I have a list `y` of endogenous values where `len(y)` = `n`
I have a n x 5 nympy array `X` of exogenous values

when I run

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.GLM(y, X).fit().summary()
```

everything runs fine.

However, when I add the `family` argument:

```
sm.GLM(y, X, family=Poisson()).fit().summary()
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'endog' and 'exog'
```

I have tried recasting the y object as numpy array, I tried explicitly declaring arguments - nothing seems to help and cannot find anything in docs to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of GLM is correct.

However, I guess your Poisson is the discrete_model.Poisson which is a separate model. GLM needs the family Poisson.

The correct usage using the api should be

```
sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit().summary()
```

or with direct imports, from an example that I was working on

```
from statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model import GLM
from statsmodels.genmod import families

mod = GLM(y, x, family=families.Poisson())
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())
```